# How to make my Extension start with XCode 8

Tags: xcode8, xcode-extension

I have created an XCode 8 Extension (For Deleting Lines, Like Sublime and Android Studio). I have code-signed it and it works as expected in the Gray Xcode Test thing.

I haven't seen a single instruction on how to get it to run with "Regular" XCode? What should I do to be able to use my extension whenever I start XCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After somehow getting this to work (once) by restarting my computer, I have finally found some working instructions on how to use an Extension with XCode 8. These are the steps:

- Enable target signing for both the Application and the Source Code Extension using your developer ID.
- Product > Archive.
- Right click archive > Show in Finder.
- Right click archive > Show Package Contents.
- Open Products, Applications.
- Drag "YourExtension".app to your Applications folder.
- Go to System Preferences -> Extensions -> Xcode Source Editor and enable this extension.
- Restart XCode if necessary